# Webshim Datalist Using Ajax Breaks in IE

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax

If you check out the example in the following link in IE11, you'll see that when you go to choose an option populated from an AJAX request, the box is displayed in the wrong position and makes it very hard to choose an option.

http://afarkas.github.io/remote-list/demo/index.html

Is this a known issue or there is a confirguation option I am missing?

Works perfectly in Chrome, Mozilla and Firefox.

Any advice or workarounds to the issue would be great.

Thanks!